# Connect signals from worker class to controller class - QThreads

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

Header:

```
#ifndef CONTROLLER_THREAD
#define CONTROLLER_THREAD

#include <QThread>

class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Worker();
    ~Worker();

private slots:
    void calculateImage();

signals:
    void imageReady();
};

class Controller: public QObject
{
public:
    Worker  objWorker;
    QThread objQThread;

    Controller();
    ~Controller();

public slots:
    void receiveImage();
};

#endif // CONTROLLER_THREAD
```

Source:

```
#include <controller_thread.h>

Worker::Worker(){}
Worker::~Worker(){}

void Worker::calculateImage()
{

}

Controller::Controller()
{
    objWorker.moveToThread( &objQThread );

    connect( objWorker, objWorker::imageReady, this, receiveImage );

    objQThread.start();
}

Controller::~Controller(){}

void Controller::receiveImage()
{

}
```

I am receiving the error:

```
 error: ‘objWorker’ is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
     connect( objWorker, objWorker::imageReady, this, receiveImage );

                     ^
```

What is the meaning of this error? How to resolve?

Typing this:
`connect( objWorker, &Worker::imageReady, this, &Controller::receiveImage );`

results in :

`error: no matching function for call to ‘Controller::connect(Worker&, void (Worker::*)(), Controller*, void (Controller::*)())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is in this line:

`connect( objWorker, objWorker::imageReady, this, receiveImage );`

In a 'new' Qt5 syntax, you need to provide class name instead of object name here - `objWorker::imageReady`.

So, your connect statement should be this:

```
connect( objWorker, &Worker::imageReady, this, &Controller::receiveImage );
```

For more help with 'new' Qt5 connect syntax you can refer [here](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax)

Comment: More generally, that's how we write a **pointer to member function** in C++.

Comment: yep, detailed explanation is in docs i provided. Did not want complicate things for simple question

Comment: I typed this: `connect( objWorker, &Worker::imageReady, this, &Controller::receiveImage );`. It resulted in this error: `error: no matching function for call to ‘Controller::connect(Worker&, void (Worker::*)(), Controller*, void (Controller::*)())’
     connect( objWorker, &Worker::imageReady, this, &Controller::receiveImage );
                                                                              ^`

Comment: Also noticed, that your `Controller` class does not have `Q_OBJECT` macro in it's definition. Without it signals and slots will not work for that class

Comment: Thanks, that was one problem. Other problem was that , I need to write connect( &objWorker, rather than connect( objWorker,